# Need solution for Bootstrap modal to not post back parent page on submit in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a large form on the Index.cshtml view with a few tables that are full CRUD functionality. I do not want the main page to be refreshed when adding, editing, or deleting rows from the tables. I am using Bootstrap for the modals. This is the first time I'm having to post data to a table but don't want to post back. There's validation for required fields on the main page that fails when you do a post back, plus I do not want the already inputted data to be lost.

Partial View (for the table plus modals):

```
@model WST___Dev.ViewModels.MasterViewModel

<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto" class="tablecontainer" id="footerlinks">
    @*<a class="popup btn btn-primary" href="/StyleEditor/SaveFooterLink/0" style="margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:20px;">Add New Link</a>*@
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="AddFooterLink();">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        &nbsp;New Link
    </button>
    <br /><br />
    <table id="myDatatable" class="table table-striped table-hover small">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Target URL</th>
                <th>

                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Footer_Links_List.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Footer_Links_List[i].name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Footer_Links_List[i].target_url)
                        </td>


                        <td>
                            <button onclick="EditFooterLink()" type="button" data-id="@Model.Footer_Links_List[i].id"
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Edit Footer Link">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button onclick="ConfirmDeleteFooterLink('@Model.Footer_Links_List[i].name', '@Model.Footer_Links_List[i].id');" type="button" data-id="@Model.Footer_Links_List[i].id"
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Delete Footer Link">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
<div id="addfooterlink" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Add New Link</h3>
            </div>
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddFooterLink", "StyleEditor", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "footerlinks" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Footer_Links.name, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3 required" })
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Footer_Links.name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                <div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Footer_Links.name)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Footer_Links.target_url, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3 required" })
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Footer_Links.target_url, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                <div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Footer_Links.target_url)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="editfooterlink" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Link</h3>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("EditFooterLink", "StyleEditor", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editfooter" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Footer_Links.id)

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Footer_Links.name, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3 required" })
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Footer_Links.name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                <div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Footer_Links.name)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Footer_Links.target_url, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3 required" })
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Footer_Links.target_url, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                <div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Footer_Links.target_url)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal " id="deleteFooterLinkConfirmModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x"></i> <span class="nav-label">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete Footer Link</span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    Delete this footer link?
                    <label id="LabelFooterLinkId" hidden="hidden" name="Id"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline " data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span> Cancel</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " data-dismiss="modal" onclick="DeleteFooterLink(document.getElementById('LabelFooterLinkId').innerHTML);">
                    <span> Delete</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
            "deferRender": true,
            "pageLength": 5,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [2]
            }]
        });

    });
     function AddFooterLink() {
        $('#addfooterlink').modal('show');

    }
    function EditFooterLink() {
        $('#editfooterlink').modal('show');
    }
    function ConfirmFooterLinkDelete(Id) {
        $("#LabelFooterLinkId").html(Id);
        $('#deleteFooterLinkConfirmModal').modal('show');
    }
    function DeleteFooterLink(Id) {

        var finishUrl = '@Url.Action("DeleteFooterLinkConfirmed", "StyleEditor", new { id = 0 })';
        var finishUrl = finishUrl.replace("0", Id);
        window.location.href = finishUrl;

    }
</script>
```

Controller Method for Add:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddFooterLink(footer_links footer_links)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.footer_links.Add(footer_links);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Json(new { Result = "OK" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Assuming there are no script errors in your page, your code should fire up the modal when user clicks "New link" button and do an ajax form submit when the click "Save" button in the modal. What is the behavior you are experiencing ?

Comment: It works fine, it just refreshes the page and I don't want it to cause I have validation in place and throws errors.

Comment: Do you have any script errors in your page. I tried your code and it did not reload the page

Comment: When you click on "Save" button it is doing a normal form submit instead of ajax submit ? Are you sure you have the needed scripts loaded ?

Comment: I'm doing a normal submit, not an ajax one. What scripts do I need? @Shyju

Comment: I'm not sure why but the button is calling the Index method and not the method I have in the form. That could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no script errors in your page, your code should fire up the modal when user clicks "New link" button. When user clicks the Save button it does a form submit.  Since you are using `Ajax.BeginForm` helper method, razor should render form tag with relevant data attributes which converts the normal form submit to an ajaxified form submit.

To enable the ajaxified form submit behavior, make sure you include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` file in the page or in your layout page. You can get it from the nuget source by searching for "Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" and adding it to your project.

When this `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` loads in your page, it override the normal form submit behavior. It does a ajax form submit instead. So once you include this library, you should be able to see the ajax form submit. But your current code specifies only the updateTargetId. So when your ajax call (form submit from modal) receives a response, it will try to update the div with id "footerlinks". But your current server code is returning just a JSON structure as response. What is the point of updating your DOM with that ?

When you add a new item, you probably want to either return the markup (html) for the new item to be added to the current table  or a JSON structure representing your new entity (and you will read this response and update the DOM).

For example, you can specify the `OnSuccess` callback when using the Ajax.BeginForm helper method. The value of this will be the name of a javascript method which will be executed when the ajax call is successful.

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddFooterLink", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", 
                                  OnSuccess = "footerAdded"}))
{

}
```

and have the js method

```
function footerAdded(response) {
       //to do : Do something with the response     

}
```

If you are returning the markup for the new record, you can use the `append` method to add the new row to the existing table in the DOM.

```
function footerAdded(response) {
      $("#someTableName").append(response);
}
```

Comment: MVC doesn't like having more than one submit button on a form so I changed the Save button to go to this method:    
`function SaveFooterLink() {

        var url = "StyleEditor/AddFooterLink"; 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#addfooterlink").serialize(), 
            success: function (data) {
                $("#myDatatable").append(response);
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    }`
But now my model is coming back null. Do I have that method right?
 @shyju